# Which database would be recommend for a python client app that can work offline

Tags: python, json, database, nosql, synchronization

I am running a  Python app on a client and I need to share a JSON file with other clients and a server. The client should be able to work offline and update the JSON file. The server should also be able to edit some configuration in the JSON file.

What DB would you recommend? It should be small, simple and be able to run offline and make sync operations to online DB.

Br 
Esben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using PyBoxDB.  It is really simple and extensible, since it is all written in python.  Here's how to use it

```
from pyboxbeta import PyBox
database = PyBox("[database name]")
database.data[key] = value
```

And when you are done editing,

```
database.close
```

Heres the website: https://pybox.netlify.com/